# Standard or common Arduino library for parsing HTTP requests?

Tags: c++, http, arduino

I'm trying to get my Arduino with [Arduino Ethernet Shield](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoEthernetShield) set up as a server to understand GET and POST requests.  I found "[Web Server well structured](http://www.arduino.cc/playground/Code/WebServer)", and could modify it to meet my needs, but does something already exists in C++ that is extremely lightweight and might already be commonly used for Arduinos with Arduinos Ethernet Shields?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've used [Webduino](http://code.google.com/p/webduino/) with my Arduino ethernet shield. It handles GET and POST requests, and reads query string parameters.

Comment: You are a saint among men.  Thanks.

Comment: I'm the developer of Webduino... hope it worked well for you!

Answer (score 0):

I've previously used the [Abyss Web Server](http://www.aprelium.com/abyssws/) for embedding a small, lightweight C++ web server into Linux programs. Hopefully this will have a low enough footprint for you.

Comment: I'd need access to the source code to trim out what I want (my entire compiled program needs to be under 30K)